# NumberFormatException with liquibase diff command

Tags: diff, liquibase

I am getting a NumberFormatException error while running liquibase diff command. Am I missing something here ?

---

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/****** Object:  Default dbo.Set_To_Zero    Script
te: 02/02/01 14:51:51 ******/
CREATE DEFAULT Set_To_Zero
        AS 0"
```

---

```
Command run: liquibase diff
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <preConditions onFail = 'HALT'>
        <dbms type="mssql" />
    </preConditions>
    <changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sqlFile-example" >
        <comment>A sample change log 1</comment>
        <sqlFile
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            path="updateEMP.sql"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

---

```
--Contents of updateEMP.sql
update dbo.EMP set dob = getdate() where id = 1
```

Thanks in advance,
luwang

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to double check your command. The error you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with the changelog and sql file you posted. Can you show the liquibase command line you ran?

Comment: liquibase.properties has the below properties  url: jdbc:sqlserver://<dbhost>:1433;databaseName=<db1>;integratedSecurity=true;  referenceUrl: jdbc:sqlserver://<dbhost>:1433;databaseName=<db2>;integratedSecurity=true;